# Eyes on Mars; are these craters mentioned or described in any paper or (scientific) article?

Tags: mars, geology, crater

[image: Big eyes on Mars]
Credit: NASA/JPL/University of Arizona
[HiRISE ESP_025334_2035](https://uahirise.org/ESP_025334_2035)
For a closer view, click on the image, and then, click again.

This pair of similar craters is located in the northern part of Oyama crater, near [Mawrth Vallis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mawrth_Vallis) on Mars.
According to [Mars Trek](https://trek.nasa.gov/mars/) they are both 4-5 km wide and about 200-300 m deep.
As far as I know these two (probably unnamed) craters are unique on Mars, yet I couldn't find any record or description of them, not even on the HiRISE page for the image above.
So it looks like for geologists it was not worth writing about them, but to me they look special, in particular the shiny "pupils" inside the "irises" with the radial grooves.
According to [these HiRISE pages](https://uahirise.org/results.php?keyword=oyama+candidate&order=release_date&submit=Search) Oyama crater was once a candidate landing site for a 2020 mission.